# What does the graviton-matter Feynman scattering diagram look like?

Tags: gravity, feynman-diagrams

The question is in the title really. I know gravity + QFT is on shaky ground but I'm not looking for Feynman rules, just a schematic, if that is possible.

Edit 1: added possible diagram for clarification.

[image: Possible diagram]

**Edit 2: Actually, isn't *this* diagram the most important?**
[image]
G represents a graviton and m represents some matter, e.g. proton, or quark.

Comment: Your diagram looks OK - encapsulates the fact that gravitons can couple to themselves and to matter.

Comment: You would probably be interested in [Feynman's lectures on gravitation](http://www.amazon.com/Feynman-Lectures-Gravitation-Frontiers-Physics/dp/0813340381) (not to be confused with his popular level lectures "On the Character of Physical Law" where he discusses gravity at length). He derives GR from the quantum field theory of spin 2 particles.

Comment: @MichaelBrown Thanks for the suggestion! Do you know if there are gluon-matter scattering diagrams in that book?

Comment: @user16307 It's been a while since I've read it but I'm certain there are. I need to check it out again. :)

Comment: @MichaelBrown Fancy scanning the image, added with some words to make an answer? :)

Comment: @user16307 :) Unfortunately I don't have it. I'd have to go to the uni library. The diagrams would look just like yours though.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, let me comment on the "gravity + QFT" statement. For sufficiently small curvatures, where we can neglect the effects of quantum gravity, we can treat excitations of gravitational field as normal spin-2 particles.
Exactly in this spirit the field of [QFT in curved space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory_in_curved_spacetime) was created. This theory describes well the interactions of ordinary particles with gravitons. It is an effective field theory that breaks down at some very high energy, when higher order terms come into play and cannot be neglected. The problem only occurs when we try to interpret the theory as a fundamental and take this cut-off energy to infinity, as this results in divergences at high energies.

Returning to your question, in the approximation of small curvatures i.e. in QFT in curved background, the interactions of gravitons are just like interactions of any other gauge field e.g. gluon, except that if couples to everything that has mass.

Comment: To be absolutely certain, could I ask you to inspect the image I have drawn and uploaded. The black line represents, say, a proton, and the red line is the graviton.

Comment: Yes, this diagram will contribute to physical processes. Just a comment: please remember that feynman diagrams are just perturbative calculation tools, this particular one will depend on the arbitrary gauge choise, so it self does not represent the full physical process.