# Elementary particles and distortion of spacetime?

Tags: gravitational-waves, elementary-particles

Are elementary particles distorted when hit by gravitational waves?

If they are, how much can they be distorted near a black hole merger? Can that distortion somehow break the particle? In that case, what are the emitted particles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elementary particles, such as the electron, the photon and the quark, have (as far as we know) no internal structure and no spatial extent so there is nothing to be distorted or broken by gravitational waves.

Since we do not yet have a theory of quantum gravity, it is impossible to say what effect a sufficiently strong gravitational wave might have on composite particles such as the proton or the neutron.

Comment: So it is not true that quarks when stretched by a GW will emit gamma rays.  I asked chatgpt and Bard and they gave me this answer.

Comment: Chatgpt is particularly known to lie...

Comment: @MarcoAltieri A point particle has no extent that can be stretched, it is a quantum mechanical entity and its **interactions** have to be modeled quantuum mechanically, with Feynman diagrams. Assuming that gravity is quantized finally,  the interaction  of a graviton with quark  *might* lead to the production of a photon if the quantum number  and other conservation laws allow it. Relevant  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52303/what-does-the-graviton-matter-feynman-scattering-diagram-look-like

Answer (score 1):

On a general note... the notion of "elementary particles" is a pretty poor mental model of quantum mechanics. It is much better to think of spacetime as showing effects like "polarization". This is one of the reasons why historically physicists were, falsely, so keen on the notion of an ether, because many effects of quantum mechanics of the vacuum are similar to that of a matter distribution. Even the notion of "particles" still evokes the mechanics of a corpuscular distribution of "objects". That, however, is not how the physical vacuum works at this level.

Instead think of the vacuum as having the ability to transfer energy to (and from) a classical system which we call "detector" that is placed in it. The amount of this exchanged energy is called "a quantum". Quanta come in different shapes and sizes like photons, electrons, muons, neutrinos, quarks etc.. In a homogeneous space of infinite dimensions and without having supplied this energy externally the physical vacuum is empty of these quanta. That's the ground state. If we distort spacetime like gravity does, however, then we are raising the net energy density (a gravitating body has mass energy), the physical vacuum will be above its ground state and there will be a net flux of quanta... in other words, space will begin to "glow". This glow is extremely faint, though. It's much, much weaker than even the cosmic microwave background for all known black holes and currently unmeasurable. Indeed the net influx of CMB quanta actually raises the masses of black holes in the current era of the universe. I doubt that even a black hole merger causes a measurable release of photons. That they have to be there is, at least for now, merely a prediction of theory.